# Call to a member function getValue() on null to fetch store config value in Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

There is error Call to a member function getValue() on null magento 2.4.6 after upgrading from Magento 2.3.3 to 2.4.6. It was working fine with earlier Magento 2 version.
Here is code:

```
public function isModuleEnable() {
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('ordergrid/general/enable', $storeScope);
}
```

The system.xml file is fine as it was working earlier. It's throwing error on getValue on null.

Comment: Show your full class.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the value of ordergrid/general/enable path in core_config_data ?

Comment: Yes I checked and this exists in Database. It isn't picking any store config value. That's strange.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface` class in your constructor:

Code like below

```
protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
     ...
     \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface $scopeInterface,
     ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeInterface;
    ...
}


public function isModuleEnable() {
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('ordergrid/general/enable', $storeScope);
}
```

Comment: I already added this dependency in constructor. I know how to get the value but the problem is it's throwing error. That's what I wanted to know if there is any other pattern used in latest version that I am missing.